# How do I get "restart" option in the shutdown menu in Unity?

Tags: unity, unity-2d, power-management, menu, power-cog

The dropdown menu I get when I click on the gear link in the top right corner only shows these options:

- Lock Computer
- Logout
- Suspend
- Hibernate
- Shutdown

There is no "restart" or "reboot".

How can I make that option available?

**Bonus question:** Can I remove Hibernate, Lock, and Suspend?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The removal of the *Restart* menu item was a [deliberate design decision](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-session/+bug/815077) - and to enforce this the developers actually removed the code...

Thus - the gconf/dconf entry...

[image]

... is actually a redundant entry that should have/but hasnt been removed.

To get the restart menu option back you will need to download the source code ([oneiric v0.3.7](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-session) at the time of writing this) and  to add back the code that was removed...

Fortunately #post11 of the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-session/+bug/815077) gave some example code of how to make the menu option reappear.  If you want to go down this route - you'll need to manually merge in the changes since the diff patch no longer marry up with the current code content.

Happy compiling :)

Answer (score 1):

I have Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS and experienced the same problem, my menu didn't show "Restart" and "Shutdown" anymore.

I installed https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/dconf-tools/.
In the left tree select `apps > indicator-session` and check/uncheck the following options:

- Check `suppress-logout-menuitem`
- Check `suppress-logout-restart-shutdown`
- Uncheck `suppress-restart-menuitem`
- Uncheck `suppress-shutdown-menuitem`

With these settings the "Restart" and "Shutdown" options appear again in the top right menu.

Answer (score -1):

You don't. It's been moved to the shutdown dialog, which is quite appropriate, I think. You can also press super and enter "reboot", or even drag reboot to your launcher, if you *really* want quick access to it. :)

Comment: What shutdown dialog? When I click shutdown in the menu, my computer immediately shuts down.

Comment: That's a bug then.