# How do I get “restart” option in the system menu in Gnome Classic?

Tags: gnome, gui, restart, gnome-classic

I previously asked [a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67927/how-do-i-get-restart-option-in-the-shutdown-menu-in-unity) about Unity, but now I'm using (and sticking with) Gnome Classic.

There is this drop down menu in the top right corner of the Gnome panel:

[image: dropdown]

When you press "Shut down", you get a dialog window that comes up with the following options:

[image: shutdown options]

However, because I probably restart as much or more than shut down, and I *never* suspend or hibernate, I'd like to move the "Restart" from the dialog window to the drop down.

Is it possible to place a "restart" option right into the dropdown menu?

Comment: It's called the Indicator Applet Session (at least in 10.04)

Comment: @charlesbridge: I thought the Indicator Applet Session referred to where all the inidcators, like Bluetooth and sound and system messages were displayed.

Comment: Indicator Applet is the container for them.  If you open gconf-editor you'll see /apps/indicator-session controls if logout / restart / shutdown options are displayed.

Comment: @charlesbridge: Thank you for the tip. I went into gconf-editor, and there were keys marked "suppress-logout", which I took to mean that if they were checked, then that meant the item would *not* show. However, regardless of checked or not, no editing of the keys made any difference to the drop down menu in question.

Comment: @Dave - the 11.10 indicator-applet is now available in a PPA (http://askubuntu.com/questions/69377/i-cant-add-a-indicator-applet-to-panel-in-gnome-classic) - however - if you use this, the reason why you cant have a restart menu option still applies as per my answer in you previous question... :(

Comment: @fossfreedom: Okay, at least now I know why the check boxes in gconf-editor didn't do anything. I don't mind that they killed the option in Unity... makes Unity suck IMHO, but I'm sure there are people out there who want to have no choices. That it got killed in Gnome Classic as well, though... arrgh!

Comment: ... dont think Canonical are responsible for the Gnome-Classic bit... personally I like the new indicator-applet (since I can now have my indicators back!) and have removed the ugly gnome applets as per standard gnome-classic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible without rewriting the source code for GNOME Panel. The actions in the menu you're referring to are constructed from [this list](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/oneiric/gnome-panel/oneiric/view/head:/gnome-panel/panel-action-button.c#L284), which does not include a restart item and isn't extensible using configuration files.

If you're feeling ambitious and want to patch in a restart menu item for yourself, creating a `panel_session_manager_request_restart` analog of [this function](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/oneiric/gnome-panel/oneiric/view/head:/gnome-panel/libpanel-util/panel-session-manager.c#L228) would be the place to start.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have the skills to write my own patch. However, knowing that it's not definitely not possible is as valid an answer, so I guess this answer is the correct one. I'll just have to hope that Gnome-Classic gets as much development attention as the other shells for future bug fixes and feature additions.